# Container-agnostic Websockets for JVM

Tags: java, ajax, jvm, websocket

Is there a container-agnostic WebSocket implementation for the JVM?  From what I can tell, everything out there is container specific (ie requires Tomcat/JBoss).

It's supported by Java EE (https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/jsr_356_java_api_for) ... but implementations require a specific server.

> As part of the Java EE 7 standard, all Java EE 7-compliant application
>   servers will have an implementation of the WebSocket protocol that
>   adheres to JSR 356. Vos explains:

I suppose embedded Jetty would be the closest...

Comment: I highly doubt it, given that websockets are not pure HTTP.

Comment: Be sure you use Jetty 9.1 for `javax.websocket` support.